# How to configure Wildfly poolsize and MDB's maxSession while keeping it scalable at runtime?

Tags: java, wildfly, message-queue, activemq-artemis

Let's assume I have a Wildfly pool, `my-pool`, configured in the Wildfly standalone:

```xml
<strict-max-pool name="my-pool" max-pool-size="1" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
```

I configure a `MessageListener` MDB to be a part of this pool, where `maxSession` is 1:

```java
@ResourceAdapter("remote-artemis")
@MessageDriven(name = "MyMDB", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "a_queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "1")
})
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@Pool(value = "my-pool")
public class MyMDB implements MessageListener { ... }
```

If I need to increase the value of maxSession on my MDB I would have to *at least* restart my application. Overall this solution does not seem very scalable. *(Know that the maxSession propertyValue can be configured as a system-property in Wildfly, but this would still require a restart of the application.)*

If I instead keep my maxSession on a higher value, or the default 15. I can adjust the poolsize in the Wildfly Management GUI at runtime. This seems more scalable, but comes with some downsides:

- Need one pool for each MDB
- 15 consumers/connections/sessions will created between the Wildfly and ActiveMQ for each MDB, even if the poolsize is set to a lower value.

**What are the suggested way to configure your Wildfly pools and MDB's maxSession, where I can still adjust the values at runtime, and only have the appropriate amount of connections between Wildfly and ActiveMQ?**

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: What do you consider to be "the appropriate amount" of connections between WildFly and ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `singleConnection` activation configuration property that will create all the sessions on a single connection rather than having 1 connection per session? That may be helpful for your use-case.

Comment: @JustinBertram - This application is an Wildfly 16 application. I consider the appropriate amount of active consumers/connections to ActiveMQ to be the number of actual working consumers in my application. Not familiar with singleConnetion, will take a look.

Comment: singleConnection won't work in WildFly 16 though

Comment: @ehsavoie I have yet to read up on singleConnection, however, even if my examples use poolsize 1 and maxSession 1, that is not the real scenario. We are looking for a way to e.g. scale from 10 to 20 "threads" at runtime. That is possible having maxSession at 20 and keeping the poolsize at 10, and scaling the poolsize at runtime, but that will create unnecessary connections between Wildfly and ActiveMQ, so it feels hacky and wrong.

Comment: iirc the minimum between the maxSession and the pool size for the MDBs will be used